# При клике на label инпут radio не становится активным в компоненте Реакта

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Есть такой компонент:

```
function ColorItem({ color, chooseColor, id}) {

  return (
    <li>
      <input
        type='radio'
        className={`${colorItemStyles.radio} ${colorItemStyles[color]}`}
        id={id}
        name='colorList'
        value={color}
        onChange={chooseColor}
        required
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>xx</label>
    </li>
  );
}

export default ColorItem;
```

При клике на label, radio не становится активным. В чем может быть проблема?

//
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Посмотрите сгенерированный по итогу код. В нём label имеет атрибут for, который был бы привязан к id радио-кнопок? Есть ли id у радио-кнопок?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Разобрался. Оказалось следующее: компонент попапа добавлен в компонент sidebar (для ПК) и в гамбургер меню. Получалось что у обоих компонентов одинаковые id и label....поэтому клик по label работал на мобильном, а на ПК нет

Comment: вывод: всегда смотрите какой сгенерировался код и вывод в консоль - наше всё ))